# $K = \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$. How many subspaces does the $K$-vector space $K^2$ have?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, quotient-spaces

> Let $K = \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$, How many subspace does the $K$-vector space $K^2$ have?

**I (hope to) already know the following**

- When diving a whole number by 2, we can only obtain 0 or 1, so $K = \{0, 1\}$ and $K^2 = \{0, 1\} \times \{0, 1\}$. Therefore $K^2$ has only four elements, $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.
- Every vector space has the two trivial subspaces: itself and the zero vector space.
- A subspace has to be not empty and closed under addition and multiplication with scalars from $K$.

**My Question**

Is $V = \{0\} \times \{0,1\} \not= \emptyset$ a $K$-vector subspace? Using the addition from $K$, we obtain $(0,0) + (0,1) = (0,1) \in V$ And $\alpha \cdot (0,0) = (0,0)$ for all scalars $\alpha \in K$ and we obtain $0 \cdot (0,1) = (0,0) \in V$ as well as $1 \cdot (0,1) = (0,1) \in V$ etc.

**Short Summary of answers given**

Besides the two trivial subspaces mentioned above there are three other subspaces, the reasoning being analogous to the one for $V = \{0\} \times \{0,1\}$ above. They are

- $V_1 = \{0\} \times \{0,1\}$
- $V_2 = \{0, 1\} \times \{0\}$
- $V_3 = \{ (0,0), (1,1) \} $

Comment: The set $V=\langle (1,0)\rangle$, vector subspace of $K^2$ generated by $(1,0)$, is a subspace.

Comment: $V=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} =\{2\mathbb{Z},1+2\mathbb{Z}\}\neq\{0,1\}$. I think it could have been mentioned here before the usual notation abuse.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \neq\{0,1\}$;  for example, if we are interested in $(\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z})^2$, it will be preferable in my opinion to write $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}=\{-1,0,1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is not feedback on your work but a nice conceptual way to think about this. For feedback see the answer by 5xum.

Let's work a bit more general: Let $K$ be a field with $q$ elements.

As the dimension of $K^2$ as $K$-vector space is two, any non-trivial subspace will have dimension at most $1$. Now any non-zero vector $v\in K\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ will generate a one-dimensional subspace (and there are $q^2-1$ such vectors) but beware you might be counting several subspaces multiple times. Indeed, any non-zero multiple of $v$ will generate the same subspace (and there are $q-1$ such non-zero multiples). It follows that the number of one-dimensional subspaces of $K^2$ is given by

$$\frac{q^2-1}{q-1}=q+1.$$

Hence in your case there are $3$ one-dimensional subspaces and two trivial subspaces. Hence $5$ subspaces in total.

Comment: So the non-trivial subspaces are $\{0\} \times \{0,1\}$, $\{0,1\} \times \{0\}$ and which other one?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik What's the third non-trivial element of $K^2$?

Comment: $(1,1)$, but $(1,1) + (1,1) = (0,0)$, so $\{1\} \times \{0,1 \}$ can't be a subspace, since it's not closed under addition in $K$, right?

Comment: The set $\left\{(0,0),(1,1)\right\}$ is a subspace. The set $\left\{1\right\}\times \left\{0,1\right\}$ can't be a subspace as any subspace contains the neutral element of the underlying group. Hence any subspace must contain $(0,0)$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik It might help to write down $\{0\}\times \{0,1\}$ as $\{(0,0), (0,1)\}$ and $\{0\}\times\{1,0\}$ as $\{(0,0), (1,0)\}$. This gives you a better idea what the third subspace should be.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\{0\}\times\{0,1\}$ is indeed a $K$-vector subspace. You almost completed your proof, but it has some flaws you should still fix. Remember, to prove that $U\subset V$ is a vector subspace (over some field $F$), you need to prove two things:

- For **every pair** $u_1, u_2\in U$, the element $u_1+u_2$ is also in $U$. In other words, $$\forall u_1, u_2\in U: u_1+u_2\in U$$
- For **every** $u\in U$, and **every** $\alpha\in F$, the element $\alpha u$ is also in $U$. In other words, $$\forall u\in U, \alpha\in F: \alpha u\in U$$

---

So far, you have proven that $(0,0) + (0,1)$ is indeed an element of $V$, but you still have to prove that **all** pairs of elements from $V$ add up to elements of $V$. This includes pairs of identical elements!

Also, I don't like the sentence

> $\alpha \cdot (0,1)$ will be either $(0,0)$ or $(0,1)$ because of the way addition in $K$ works.

which I think you should rewrite. First of all, it's not because of the way *addition* works, it's about how *multiplication* works (sure, the two are related, but it's better form). Second, it's better if you just write down all the possibilities, since there are only two options for $\alpha$ anyway.